# RDF library and SPARQL issue

Tags: python, pycharm, sparql, rdf, rdfa

In my python file I have imported rdflib and implemented some SPARQL query to for some testing. Here is the code I have now.

```
from rdflib import Graph

if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = Graph()

    g.parse('http://localhost:8085/weather-2.html', format='rdfa')

res1 = g.parse('http://localhost:8085/weather-2.html', format='rdfa')
print(res1.serialize(format='pretty-xml').decode("utf-8"))
print()

res2 = g.query("""SELECT ?obj
    WHERE { <http://localhost:8085/weather-2.html> weather:region obj . }
    """)
for row in res2:
    print(row)
```

I ran my code and got this error.

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
```

Is this because of the directory of my file `weather-2.html`?

Or this there something I am missing in my imlpementation?

I am using pycharm as my editor and yes I did remember to install all the packages so I am not sure what causing this error.

Comment: Is the file `http://localhost:8085/weather-2.html` available under this URL?

Comment: weather prefix is also not declared.

Comment: Well I I managed to solve my connection error but now I get the weather prefix error as u stated. Not sure why since I did insert 'weather:region' what does it mean by 'Exception: Unknown namespace prefix : weather'?

Comment: This I feel is a simple fix but I am not sure how it looks like through syntax. Would you mind showing me how?

Comment: I have posted my new question in regards to this issue. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50610084/sparql-unknown-namespace-prefix-error