# SPARQL - Unknown namespace prefix error

Tags: python, pycharm, sparql, rdflib, rdfa

I have a python file with imported rdflib and some SPARQL query implemented

```
from rdflib import Graph
import html5lib

if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = Graph()

    g.parse('http://localhost:8085/weather-2.html', format='rdfa')

res1 = g.parse('http://localhost:8085/weather-2.html', format='rdfa')
print(res1.serialize(format='pretty-xml').decode("utf-8"))
print()

res2 = g.query("""SELECT ?obj
    WHERE { <http://localhost:8085/weather-2.html> weather:region ?obj . }
    """)
for row in res2:
    print(row)
```

res1 has no trouble to print out but for res2 I get an error saying:

```
Exception: Unknown namespace prefix : weather
```

Apparently this is due to an error on line 15 according to pycharm, the editor I am using to implement this.

What am I missing that is causing this error?
Is there more to just calling `weather:region` in my SPARQL query?
If so how to do fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message suggests, the namespace `weather:` is not defined - so in the SPARQL you either need a PREFIX to define weather, like:

`PREFIX weather: <weatheruri>`

Or you should put the explicit weather URI instead of the `weather:`

The weather namespace URI (or is it called an IRI?) will be in the XML namespaces in the rdf document - it will end with / or # so if the URI is `http://weather.com/` the prefix definition is `PREFIX weather: <http://weather.com/>`

Comment: Ok I added the prefix in my rdf document and that solved the problem. Thank you.